# kill previous nrepl sessions when nrepl-jack-in called?

Tags: emacs, clojurescript

At this moment in time, I am using nrepl primarily to talk to Clojurescript apps. I like to use nrepl from within emacs. I start nrepl by typing `M-x nrepl-jack-in`.

Unfortunately, my nrepl session often gets completely hung. When this happens, I dutifully kill the 3 buffers related to nrepl. These buffers are:

1. `*nrepl*`
2. `*nrepl-connection*`
3. `*nrepl-server*`

`*nrepl-server*` also has an active process, it ask me if I want to close it, and I say yes.

I then type `M-x nrepl-jack-in` again.

**This is a pain.**

I would like to overload `nrepl-jack-in` so that it automatically checks if any of these 3 buffers exist. If any of them do exist, it will kill these buffers and any active processes associated with these bufers. After doing this, the overloaded `nrepl-jack-in` will proceed as usual. I would like this because then, whenever I detect that nrepl has decided to hang itself again, I could just type `M-X nrepl-jack-in` and restart what I was doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get the job done:

```
(defun my-nrepl-jack-in ()
  (interactive)
  (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
    (when (string-prefix-p "*nrepl" (buffer-name buffer))
      (kill-buffer buffer)))
  (nrepl-jack-in nil))
```

Comment: I get the following error in \*Messages* when I type `M-x my-nrepl-jack-in` :
my-nrepl-jack-in: Wrong number of arguments: #[(prompt-project) "ÄÅÆÇ! # ÈÉÊ
#ËÌ\"ÍÎ\"ÏÐ#ÑÒ!*" [prompt-project nrepl-server-command cmd process format "cd %s && %s" ido-read-directory-name "Project: " start-process-shell-command "nrepl-server" ...] 4 nil "P"], 0

Answer (score 4):

The chosen answer didn't quite work for me... The nrepl process sentinel threw an error, preventing it from restarting. I played with it a bit and came up with the following (which also gives a separate `kill-nrepl` function)

```
;; Disable prompt on killing buffer with a process
(setq kill-buffer-query-functions
      (remq 'process-kill-buffer-query-function
            kill-buffer-query-functions))

(defun nrepl-kill ()
  "Kill all nrepl buffers and processes"
  (interactive)
  (when (get-process "nrepl-server")
    (set-process-sentinel (get-process "nrepl-server")
                          (lambda (proc evt) t)))
  (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
    (when (string-prefix-p "*nrepl" (buffer-name buffer))
      (kill-buffer buffer))))

(defun nrepl-me ()
  (interactive)
  (nrepl-kill)
  (nrepl-jack-in nil))
```

Comment: The sentinel normally would ask you simply for confirmation to kill the underlying buffer process. Restarting worked for me when I tried it, but obviously I wouldn't go committing the code as is upstream ;-)